# How to insert multiple custom fields to whmcs API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, whmcs

I have an issue to insert multiple product custom fields to whmcs using laravel. In this below code pass the $cp value alone. But  need to pass the $os,$db and $cp value.

```
$order_details = Whmcs::AddOrder([
            'clientid' => $value,
            'paymentmethod' => 'razorpay',
            'pid' => $pid,
            'domain' => $domain,
            'billingcycle' => $billingcycle,
            'domaintype' => $domain_reg,
            'regperiod' => $domain_regperiod,
    'customfields'=>array(base64_encode(serialize($os))),
    'customfields'=>array(base64_encode(serialize($db))),
    'customfields'=>array(base64_encode(serialize($cp)))
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom fields are presented in the form as following:

```
<input name="customfield[5]" type="text">
<input name="customfield[11]" type="text">
```

And when submitted, the post vars is:

```
$_POST['customfield'] = array('5' => '', '11' => '' );
```

So when using AddOrder function the code becomes:

```
//using Laravel $request
$customFields = base64_encode(serialize($request->input('customfield')));
//or using $_POST array
$customFields = base64_encode(serialize($_POST['customfield']));

$order_details = Whmcs::AddOrder([
            'clientid' => $value,
            'paymentmethod' => 'razorpay',
            'pid' => $pid,
            'domain' => $domain,
            'billingcycle' => $billingcycle,
            'domaintype' => $domain_reg,
            'regperiod' => $domain_regperiod,
            'customfields'=> $customFields
        ]);
```

Comment: ALWAYS sanitize data coming from $_POST $_REQUEST or $_GET

Comment: Yeah i figured, just like to mention it to always get people in the habit of sanitizing data ... even if you're only checking direct `===` always good to still sanitize, as you may change code later and forget to do it :)